# react-native:Show spinner at the center of the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to show the spinner at the center of screen.I used alignItems, justifyContent and flex but there is no change in the position then i use margintop for correct positioning.why there is no change on the use of alignItems,justifyContent and flex?

here i m using spinner.

```
 return (
  <View style={style.spinnerStyle}>
  <Spinner size ="large" />
  </View>
 );
 const style = {
spinnerStyle: {
  flex: 1,
  marginTop:240
}
};
```

Spinner.js

```
  import React from 'react';
  import {View,ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';

  const Spinner = ({size}) => {
  return (
  <View style = {styles.spinnerStyle}>
  <ActivityIndicator size={size || 'large'} />
  </View>
  );
 };

const styles = {
spinnerStyle: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems:'center'
 }
 };

export { Spinner };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you please try with following:

where you are using Spinner

```
spinnerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop:240,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:'center'
}
```

In Spinner

```
spinnerStyle: {
    flex: 1
    alignSelf:'center'
}
```

Comment: it worked :-) but why it is not working when i use justifyContent,alignItems in spinner.

Comment: You need to add it on parent component

Comment: This answer is wrong. Using marginTop is a hack that does not take into account all of the different device screen sizes. Please see my answer for the correct way to vertically center the ActivityIndicator component.

Comment: @ErinGeyer, If you look closely I just copied the CSS part used by the OP and added new lines which would be handling center alignment. I had not suggested to add marginTop, and believed that it would be his requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    spinnerStyle: { 
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
 }
});
```

Comment: Respectfully, this is overly complex and incorrect, unfortunately. Please see my answer for the correct implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to vertically center the ActivityIndicator component is to use 'flex: 1' on the ActivityIndicator component itself, not on its parent component. It does not need a wrapper component and none of the other flex alignment styles are necessary at all.

The improved implementation of the OP's code would be:

```
import React from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';

const Spinner = ({size}) => {
  return (
    <ActivityIndicator size={size || 'large'} style={{ flex: 1 }}/>
  );
 };

export { Spinner };
```

Comment: the only proper answer

Answer (score -1):

Set in spinner parent view:

```
justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems:'center'
```

And in spinner set:

```
alignSelf:'center'
```